# What is the relation between power and Prime Minister?

Tags: political-system

In a country with a parliamentary or semi-presidential political system, there is a Prime Minister. Is it that a person becomes Prime Minister because he/she is powerful or is it that you become powerful once you have become the Prime Minister?

Comment: This is going to depend on the country and will be different depending on the circumstances in each country.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most countries with a parliamentary system, the key qualification for a prime minister is to **have the confidence of a majority** of parliament. There are two ways to get there:

- The prime minister is the leader of a powerful faction, either with a majority or able to build a coalition, or
- the prime minister is the *acceptable compromise candidate* for a coalition which may contain more powerful individuals, but who cannot organize a majority of their own.

The latter case is rather uncommon, and it would probably lead to the compromise prime minister gaining in power.

Comment: A key factor of the first point is that the leader of a powerful faction may keep getting support to keep that powerful faction in power.

Answer (score -1):

**Short answer**: The Prime Minsiter only becomes powerful once the Parliament has granted them the mandate to be Prime Minister.

**Long annswer**: Under both parliamentary systems and semi-presidential systems, the Prime Minsiter is responsible to the Parliament, meaning that the Parliament can dismiss them any time. Therefore, the Prime Minister is only powerful as long as the parliament has **confidence** in them.

The Prime Minister is considered powerful if they have a strong majority backing them in Parliament, whereas they are considered weak if they have an unstable parliamentary majority ready to withdraw support anytime.

Comment: And the prime ministers that have power before getting the job? There is generally a reason that people get picked for the job and part of that reason can be the power they hold outside of the the job.

Comment: @JoeW What do you mean precisely? I can't imagine any Prime Minister being able to stay in office against the confidence of parliament because of a job they hold outside of parliament.

Comment: Sure but they generally have to mess up big time to actually get voted out of office. Look at the UK and Boris Johnson right now there are lots of calls for him to be removed but it seems he still has his party's backing. There is a big difference between saying a prime minister can be removed and them actually getting removed. Generally the party in power isn't going to take actions that can remove them from power. They may have no confidence in the person who is prime minister but if removing him means they lose power the prime minister can easily stay in power.

Comment: @JoeW If the UK Parliament no longer has confidence in Johnson then they would've ousted him with a no-confidence vote. The fact that he is still in office implies that the UK Parliament does have confidence in him - it's that simple. Being Conservative Party leader does not make you immune to vote of no confidence if that's what you are suggesting.

Comment: That is not necessarily true, a party isn't going to throw away their power without a very good reason. Members of the party have to make a decision is the lack of confidence strong enough to be okay with the lack of power that could come as a result of removing the prime minister from power. You need to remember that the power to remove a prime minister only matters if the prime minister doesn't have enough power to prevent it from getting enough votes.

Comment: I am not saying it is impossible to remove a prime minister from power, just that it is not always as easy as it sounds as the people in power will still vote for a person to ensure they stay in power.

Comment: @JoeW OP questions is about the source of a Prime Minister's power - which is and always will be from the Parliament. You are confusing the scope of the question by going on a tangent about party leadership. From what I can gather, your understanding of parliamentary system is restricted to just UK where two-party domiannce is the norm.  It completely ignores the fact that in other countries that have multi-party systems, the Prime Minsiter's source power rests on holding their parliamentary coalition together. Party leadership does not bestow right to govern - parliament does.

Comment: And I am saying that the parliament doesn't always have the ability to vote out a prime minister because of the power they hold not only from their position but what they have outside of it. Just because there is the possibility of removing a prime minister from power doesn't mean that there is any chance of it actually happening.